# 誤って rm -f /* を実行し、いくつかのファイルが削除されてしまいました

Tags: linux, centos

`rm -f ./*` を実行するつもりが `rm -f /*` としてしまって色々消してしまいました。

ls は

```
-bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory
```

また yum も

```
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

と出ます。大半のコマンドが使えず、wget などを実行するとこのようなエラーが出ます。

```
-bash: /usr/bin/wget: /lib64/Id-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

OSはCentOS7です。

解決策として何が挙げられるのかご教授ください。

補足
諦めて再インストールします。
ただ自分は解決法知ってるよ、という方は是非過ちを犯してしまった別の方のために回答をよろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 仮想環境下でスナップショットを取っていたらそれを戻せばなんとかなりますが、ない場合はどうしようもないかもしれません。少し前に話題になったrm -rf /と違って--preserve-rootが効かないようですね。http://serverfault.com/questions/337082/how-do-i-prevent-accidental-rm-rf

Comment: まじですか・・・
じゃあ、またOS再インストールしたほうがいいんですかね。。。

Comment: あれっ、でもこの場合だと/以下のディレクトリはのこっているんですよね？

Comment: ファイルシステムが ext3 か ext4 であれば [extundelete: An ext3 and ext4 file undeletion utility](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) というプログラムがあります。ただ、**There is no guarantee that any particular file will be able to be undeleted** ではありますが。

Comment: どういう環境か分かりませんが、そのマシンへは物理的にHDDを取り外して別マシンで接続したりできますか？別マシンでROM化して書込み禁止から復旧した話を聞きましたが……

Answer (score 13):

CentOS7/64bitの場合、4種のシンボリックリンク `/lib64`, `/lib`, `/bin`, `/sbin` が削除されていますので、それらを貼り直すことで復旧できますね。

```
# /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /usr/lib64 /usr/bin/ln -s /usr/lib64 /lib64
# /usr/bin/ln -s /usr/bin /bin
# ln -s /usr/lib /lib
# ln -s /usr/sbin /sbin
```

参考として、他ディストリビューションについて既出のものがありましたのでリンクを:

- (Ubuntu)[data recovery - Accidentally executed sudo rm /* on a remote server - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18370)
- (Debian)[debian - Can I recover from "rm /*"? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/484513)

リンク先にある通り、Ubuntuではbusyboxが標準でインストールされているようなので、それを用いて回復できるようですね。

---

仮想環境のCentOS7/64bitで同様のコマンドを実行してみた結果が以下になります。

```
[root@localhost /]# ls -l
total 32
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    8 May  9 01:08 bin -> /usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   5 root root 4096 Apr  6 22:37 boot
drwxr-xr-x.  20 root root 3160 May  9 01:03 dev
drwxr-xr-x.  81 root root 8192 May  9 01:02 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root   17 Aug 12  2015 home
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    8 May  9 01:08 lib -> /usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root   10 May  9 01:07 lib64 -> /usr/lib64
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Aug 12  2015 media
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root   18 Feb 13 19:28 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   4 root root   51 Apr  6 22:44 opt
dr-xr-xr-x. 165 root root    0 May  9 01:02 proc
dr-xr-x---.   3 root root 4096 May  9 01:03 root
drwxr-xr-x.  24 root root  760 May  9 01:03 run
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    9 May  9 01:08 sbin -> /usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Aug 12  2015 srv
dr-xr-xr-x.  13 root root    0 May  9 01:02 sys
drwxrwxrwt.   8 root root 4096 May  9 01:03 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root 4096 Feb 13 16:29 usr
drwxr-xr-x.  20 root root 4096 May  9 01:02 var


[root@localhost /]# rm -fv /*
removed '/bin'
rm: cannot remove '/boot': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/dev': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/etc': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/home': Is a directory
removed '/lib'
removed '/lib64'
rm: cannot remove '/media': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/mnt': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/proc': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/root': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/run': Is a directory
removed '/sbin'
rm: cannot remove '/srv': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/sys': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/tmp': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/usr': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/var': Is a directory
```